# Accusative of Duration of Space

Tags: accusative

I am working through Jenney's Second-Year Latin and I came across this sentence:

Pyrrhus Romanos mille octingentos cepit, eosque summo honore tractavit.

It's the first clause that's giving me the trouble.  I think it means Pyrrhus captured the Romans after eight-hundred miles.  I would have written post octingentos millium. I don't understand the construction mille octingentos.  Is my translation even correct?

Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

*Mille* isn't "miles", it's just the number "[thousand](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mille#Latin)." The translation is actually that "Pyrrhus captured 1,800 (1,000 + 800) Romans."

What you're probably thinking of is *mille passuum*, which is more literally "a thousand paces", i.e. a "mile." But for that to be mile, you really do need the *passuum*. Without that, it's more natural to read the accusative plural *octingentos* with the other accusative plural *Romanos*.

Answer (score 5):

There are two separate numbers: mille (one thousand) and octingentos (eight hundred). So, it is:

*Pyrrhus captured one thousand, eight hundred Romans, and treated them with the greatest respect.*